# I can't display user data from GitHub's API in a React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I know there are errors in my code but being a React newbie, I can't figure them out. My goal is to fetch users from the `api` and render their email and bio on screen once the button is pressed.

```
class App extends Component {
 state = {
   users: []
 }

 async getUser(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const username = e.target.elements.username.value;
   const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}`);
   const user = await profileResponse.json();
   this.setState({ users: this.state.users.concat([user]) });
 }

 render() {
 return (
 <div className="App">
   <h1>Search users</h1>
   <p>Enter a username to fetch a user.</p>
   <form onSubmit={this.getUser}>
     <input 
       type="text"
       name="username" 
       placeholder="GitHub username"
     />
     <button>Find User</button>
   </form>

   { this.state.users.length > 0 && this.state.users.map((user) => <p key={user.login}>{user.email, user.bio}</p>) }

 </div>
 );
 }
}
export default App;
```

The error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {login, id, avatar_url, gravatar_id, url, html_url, followers_url,
>   following_url, gists_url, starred_url, subscriptions_url,
>   organizations_url, repos_url, events_url, received_events_url, type,
>   site_admin, name, company, blog, location, email, hireable, bio,
>   public_repos, public_gists, followers, following, created_at,
>   updated_at}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

Comment: Try `{user.email}, {user.bio}</p>`, but ensure email and bio are not objects

Comment: The API returns an object. It's something to do with setting the state (which is an array) to the object returned from the API. But I can't figure out what's the best way to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your example, I received the following error :

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Transforming `getUser` to an arrow function fixed it : `getUser = async (e) => {}`

Further reading : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Second problem :

`{user.email, user.bio}` in render won't work replace with `{user.email} {user.bio}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue:

```
{user.email, user.bio}
```

The solution is:

```
{user.email}, {user.bio}
```

Also, you need to make sure that user.email and user.bio are not objects.

You need to handle the case where the response that you receive from the API is not a user object, for example if the user you are looking for doesn't exist.